# How to search multiple inputs and checkboxes with php pdo?

Tags: php, checkbox, pdo

I have a search form with multiple "text" inputs currently functioning which I am trying to add checkboxes to.. After adding the checkboxes, I'm getting the following:

> ERROR: Array to String Conversion

```
<form action='s-response.php method='get'>
<div class='cusname'><input type='text' name='cusname' class='EdtTxt' /></div>
<div class='street'><input type='text' name='street' class='EdtTxt' /></div>
```

Checkboxes

```
<?php while ($row=$query->fetch()){?>
    <input type='checkbox' name='groupid[]' value='<?php echo $row['id'];?>'><?php echo $row['title'];?><?php }?>
```

RESPONSE PAGE

```
$wheres = array();
$params = array();
/* Find all Sent fields, If the field is Not Empty, add the field to the SQL query */
if (!empty($_GET['cosname'])) { $wheres[] = 'c.cname LIKE :cosname'; $params[':cosname'] = '%'.$_GET['cosname'].'%'; }
if (!empty($_GET['street'])) { $wheres[] = 'a.street LIKE :street'; $params[':street'] = '%'.$_GET['street'].'%'; }
```

Checkbox Part

```
if(!empty($_GET['groupid'])) {

foreach($_GET['groupid'] as $value){
    $wheres[] = 'g.groupid = :groupid'; $params[':groupid'] = $_GET['groupid'];
}}
```

Query Part

```
/* Create the Start and End (static) parts of the query */
$q1="SELECT c.fname,a.street FROM customers c LEFT JOIN cus_address a ON c.id=a.custid WHERE c.act=1";
$q3=" GROUP BY c.id";
/* Create the Middle (dynamic) part of the query */
if (!empty($wheres)) { $q1 .= " AND " . implode(' AND ', $wheres); }
/* Combine into one query and execute */
$sql=$q1.$q3;
$query=$con->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($params);
```

Any idea what is causing the error?

Comment: `ERROR: Array to String Conversion` this message is incomplete... PHP tells you pretty exactly where the problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query Part

```
if(!empty($_GET['groupid'])) {

    foreach($_GET['groupid'] as $i => $value){
        $placeholder = sprintf(':groupid%d', $i+1);
        $wheres[] = sprintf('g.groupid = %s', $placeholder); 
        $params[$placeholder] = $value;
    }
}
```

In the foreach loop, you should be using `$value`, not `$_GET['groupid']` - It's an array, remember? You're currently iterating over it.

I have edited my answer to show how to handle multiple group ids. The placeholder is unique, eg. `:groupid1, :groupid2, :groupid3`.

Comment: ok thank you that solves the array error. I notice now that if I select multiple checkboxes I get different error, "Invalid parameter number" for the exeucute statement. Please let me know if you know the solution for this. @Lars Stegelitz

Comment: Because you're using the same placeholder `:groupid` again. It needs to be unique, append a number (index from the array is suitable)

Comment: hmm. i do understand what you are saying, but cannot seem to get it. I have limited experience with arrays.. So am I to change it here "'g.groupid = :groupid'" OR here $params[':groupid']; OR both @Lars Stegelitz